# Higher order function return type void ignored

Tags: typescript

I stumbled over the following issue and I wonder if it's actually a bug or it's intended and I misunderstand some [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html) behavior:

```
function foo(): void {
  return ''
}
```

> Compile error (**expected**)

```
function bar(): () => number {
  return () => ''
}
```

> Compile error (**expected**)

```
function baz(): () => string {
  return () => ''
}
```

> No compile error (**expected**)

```
function qux(): () => void {
  return () => ''
}
```

> No compile error (**not-expected**)

As we can see above:

- `foo` type says `return void` (nothing) but the function `returns a string` [compile error expected]
- `bar` type says `return a function that returns a number` but `returns a function that returns a string` [compile error expected]
- `baz` type says `return a function that returns a string` and does so [no compile error expected]
- `qux` type says `return a function that returns void` (nothing) but `returns a function that returns a string` [compile error expected]

How does it happen that **qux** throws no compile error?

[TypeScript - Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)